# Specify border for svg path element

Tags: html, svg

I am trying to to border for svg path element using stroke attribute but its not drawing border on all four borders.Any idea how to draw on all four borders

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My first SVG</h1>

<svg >
<path fill="rgba(103,103,103,.35)" d="M 149.5 8 L 149.5 40 316.5 40 316.5 8" stroke-width="3" stroke='#3fa9f5' ></path>
</svg> 



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have forgotten to close your path with `Z` like

```html
<svg  width=320 height=50 viewBox="0 0 320 50">
  <path fill="rgba(103,103,103,.35)" d="M 149.5 8 L 149.5 40 316.5 40 316.5 8 Z" stroke-width="3" stroke='#3fa9f5' ></path>
</svg>
```

This will draw the missing line too. It is also a good idea to include the `width` and `height` attributes into the `<svg>` tag.

**Some more unsolicited advice ...**
Maybe you should also include a `viewBox="0 0 320 50"` attribute into your `<svg>` tag too, as in a general case (when the svg resides in a separate file) this will make the inclusion of the svg content into other pages much easier. It will allow scaling of the svg-contents if you include it with an `<object data="mysvgdata.svg" type="image/svg+xml" width="640">` tag. The result would be similar to this:

```html
<svg  width=640 viewBox="0 0 320 50">
  <path fill="rgba(103,103,103,.35)" d="M 149.5 8 L 149.5 40 316.5 40 316.5 8 Z" stroke-width="3" stroke='#3fa9f5' ></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: can we do it without z argumen. Actallu I cannt edit z argument  or how to add z argument to existing svg path element?